# Find the minimum number of circles which you have to remove such that the remaining circles are non-intersecting

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's us assume we have 3 circles

```
3
0 0 5
0 6 3
7 0 4
```

if
the first two terms are the coordinates of cirlce (x,y)and third term is radius.

the answer would be "1"
we can remove the 1st circle and rest 2 will not intersect.

how to find such for n number of circles

Comment: What you have tried so far? Are you looking for a better algorithm than the brute-force solution?

Comment: i know it is easy to find if two circles intersect each other. i don't know how to deal with n numbers of circles

Comment: One appealing strategy would be to repeatedly delete the circle that has the most intersections, until no such circles remain.  But this simple algorithm doesn't work in general: on the problem http://imgur.com/0Mr5YNmm, it would first delete the black circle in the centre, which is the only circle with 4 intersections -- but then the largest solution you can make is 4.  If you instead leave the black circle in the solution, you can make a solution of size 5 (the black circle, plus all 4 green circles).

Comment: There is some discussion of this question on the Computer Science SE [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35876/maximum-non-intersecting-subset-of-circles)

Comment: @AlexReinking: Good link, but note that in the question they address there, all circles have the same size -- unlike here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker true, but you could probably adapt the ILP approach there. Either way, this problem is NP-Hard, so the best you can hope to do is heuristic search or approximation.

Comment: @AlexReinking: I would guess that it's NP-hard, but it's possible that it's not as it's only a special case of Independent Set -- for example, in the unrestricted IS case, suppose you have 2 non-neighbouring vertices u and v, each of which have the same set of 3 neighbours {x, y, z}, no pair of which are linked by an edge.  I can see one way to represent this using (different-sized) circles...  But if we add another vertex w that is connected to just x and y, I don't see any way to construct this using circles.